# how to add custom css style beetwen two legend in google chart

Tags: javascript, css, charts, google-visualization, bar-chart

i want to add margin-bottom css rules in this google legend. how it is possible

```
legend :{marginBottom:15px}
```

**Some like this:**

[image]